# Screen blanker problem

Tags: unity, 14.10, screensaver

Ubuntu 14.10. I have enable screen blank after 5 minutes but after that screen is turning off for one second and turning on again. My graphic card is Intel GM965:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing ubuntu-desktop-mir package problem gone :)